# jquery: on eventhandler called multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, event-handling

I wish to do the following:
Create a list(ul and li). Then on ul click, i want to insert `div` based on condition i.e. if `checkbox` is selected then created a `div` with 4 checkboxes.

If `radio` is selected from the list then a `div` is created with 4 radios.

Following is my jquery code:

```
var addDiv=document.createElement("div");

  $("#id-ul").click(function(){$('#sidr-bottom').hide();
   var div_id=0;
   addDiv=document.createElement("div");
   $( "#A_MULTI" ).on( "click", { divId:addDiv }, myHandler );
   $( "#A_RADIO" ).on( "click", { divId:addDiv }, myHandlerRadio );
   addDiv.id = "div_multi"+div_id; ...
```

checkbox handler:

```
function myHandler( event ) {
   alert("check : "+ event.data.divId );}
```

radio handler:

```
function myHandlerRadio( event ) {
    alert("radio:"+ event.data.divId );}
```

Now the problem is that when i click on `checkbox` from the list `for first time`, `myhandler` is not called.

When i click it again, handler gets called once.

When i click it once more, handler gets called twice.

What is the reason for this weird behavior?

Please let me know how do i solve this.

**edited :**

I moved the below 2 lines outside `#id-ul` click.

`$( "#A_MULTI" ).on( "click", { divId:addDiv }, myHandler );
       $( "#A_RADIO" ).on( "click", { divId:addDiv }, myHandlerRadio );`
 I still face the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are assigning event handler every time your `#id-ul` is clicked.

Please move your event outside event handler.

Comment: but then how will i pass the div to handler? div is indide the #id-ul click. Please let me know.

Comment: @z22 do you want to pass different data for each event handler? as you are creating div event type `click` event is triggered

Comment: y dont you access div using its id inside other event handler..make it simple..dont pass data to event handler..access it div using id

Comment: yes but to pass id also , i will have to write the event inside the id-ul click, right?

Comment: @z22 No my friend..Just use newly created div's id inside other event handler to access it

Comment: i am noob to jquery so can you please let me know how do i use newly created div's id inside other event handler to access it ? Also see my edited question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48649/discussion-between-z22-and-pilot)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding handlers without ever clearing them.  You should do this:

```
   $( "#A_MULTI" ).off("click").on( "click", { divId:addDiv }, myHandler );
   $( "#A_RADIO" ).off("click").on( "click", { divId:addDiv }, myHandlerRadio );
```

To remove the old handler(s) before assigning new ones.